# I want to display some columns of a table based on a subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

I want to **Display department number, names and salaries of employees who are earning max salary in their departments** which are in the same table.

I am using oracle sql. The Table structure I am using is

```
Emp(Empno,Ename,Job,Salary,Deptno)
```

I have read about this and I think that this can be done by the use of correlated sub-queries. The query I fired was

```
select E1.Ename,E1.Ename,E1.Salary
from Emp E1
where E1.Empno=(
              select Empno
              from Emp E2
              where Salary=(
                          select max(Salary)
                          from Emp
                          where Deptno=E1.Deptno
                           )
                );
```

This gives an **error saying "single-row subquery returns more than one row"**.
What am I doing wrong? What should do to correct it?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  EmpNo, Ename,Job,Salary,Deptno
FROM    
    (
        SELECT  EmpNo, Ename,Job,Salary,Deptno,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DeptNo
                                    ORDER BY Salary DESC ) rn
        FROM    Emp
    ) a
WHERE   a.rn  = 1
```

- [DENSE_RANK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions043.htm)

or by using `MAX`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Emp a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  DeptNo, MAX(Salary) Max_sal
            FROM    Emp
            GROUP   BY DeptNo
        ) b ON a.DeptNo = b.DeptNo AND
                a.Salary = b.Max_SAL
```